# finding the standard matrix for the transformation.

Tags: matrices, transformation

So assuming u=(cos x, sin x), where x is theta of course, is the direction of a line through (0,0) in R^2. And ***T*** is the operator which reflects vectors about the line. Using ***T***(e1) and ***T***(e2), How would I find the standard matrix for the transformation?

Comment: Draw a picture.

Comment: As the problem suggests, find where the two unit vectors (0,1) and (1,0) end up and then build the matrix from that (the matrix is literally the transformation of the unit vectors).